# Protection of violins when moving to a new climate

Tags: violin, instruments, maintenance

I am about to move from a hot, dry climate (Johannesburg) to a very humid, cool climate (Overberg, South Africa). Is there anything I can do to protect my violins from the impact of the climate change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only problem would seem to be the minor swelling of the wood from the additional humidity. The following precautions would be appropriate:

1. de–tune each instrument by turning the tuning pegs out 1 full turn. Loosen the tension on the bows similarly.
2. wrap each instrument in a baby blanket
3. upon introducing the instruments to their new environment open the cases and wait 24 hours before re–tuning the instruments and playing them.

Consult a luthier for additional advice.

Comment: And in the long term the instruments will be much happier in a humid cool climate.

Comment: I agree. I would be much more concerned if the change was the other way around!